# can't get Ant to work

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, cordova

I am trying to run Cordova on my ubuntu 12.04. When I try to create the project, its throwing me this error

```
k@k-cm:~/Development/Android/ionic/hello$ cordova platform add android
Checking Android requirements...
Creating android project...
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.ionic.toderp
    Name: toderp
    Android target: android-17
Building cordova-3.2.0.jar

{ [Error: Command failed: 
BUILD FAILED
/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:710: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:723: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre"

Total time: 0 seconds
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
]
```

Here is my PATH

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386:/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/k/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e:/home/k/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/k/Home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/k/Home/k/Dev/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin
```

JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

Please help!

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not set properly according to the error message: `It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre"`

Comment: Yes, the error message says that. But its set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

Comment: There must be a JDK (containing the Java compiler etc.) not only a JRE. Do you have installed package "openjdk-7-jdk" besides "openjdk-7-jre"?

Comment: verify if all is okay by entering "ant build" and see if its instalted properly.

Comment: @halfbit I have installed just JDK, not JRE. But there is a folder JRE inside my JDK folder. javac is inside JDK/bin. JAVA_HOME is set to JDK, but instead of looking inside bin, its going for JRE

Comment: @Purus ant build is throwing me this error
'Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/tools.jar'

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to that Ant can not find the tools.jar file.

You need to copy the tools.jar file and put it in the lib folder for the ant to work.

Do a search for tools.jar file in the lib folders from other sdk libraries and put that in the above path in error.

Comment: It was something to do with JAVA sdk I had. Reinstalled it and it works like a charm now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hey @Purus i have same problem. I have also reinstalled my java sdt. Could you tell me details of what i have to do with tools.jar

Comment: which tools.jar i have to put in the lib folder.. Please help

Comment: Any tools.jar file in the java related folder of jdk/sdk is fine